# Wind Turbine Generator Types

Tags: generator, induction, synchronous

I am curious about wind turbine generator types used around the world today if anybody has any experience they wish to share.

My question is mainly are most wind turbines of the synchronous or asynchronous type?

I'm guessing this has a lot do to with the rated power of the machine.

1. If asynchronous generators are used would they be DFIG's for the larger gensets and maybe permanent magnet rotors for much smaller scale turbines?
2. Are many synchronous generators are used? And are they likely to be excited by brushes or a static brushless exciter?
3. Are wind turbines ever used to power a load given there is enough wind power, and the mains actually used as a backup for when the wind turbine can't supply the load?
4. I'm guessing both types are just as tricky to sync with the grid requiring complex power electronics?

Thanks everyone

Comment: The question is too broad and will likely be closed. All types of generators are used. To what extent is difficult to determine. Asynchronous generators are only DFIG, WRIG and squirrel cage SCIG. Generators with permanent magnet rotors are synchronous (PMSG). Wound rotor synchronous generators (WRSG) are also used. Synchronization can be totally electronic or by pitch control. It takes about three 75 minute lectures to present the basics of wind turbine generation.

Comment: Thanks Charles. It maybe is a poor question but thanks for your response.